# Why is apple juice hard to order in a restaurant in Spain?

Tags: food-and-drink, spain

Traveling in Spain I noticed that it is actually very hard to order apple juice in a normal restaurant.
However you can buy some apples or apple juice in supermarkets.

Why would that be?

Comment: Did you only try to order apple juice, or did you also try asking for cider? The reason I ask is that there are well known Spanish Cider Houses. I have found quite a few menus with Apple Juice, Liquer and Cider all available. Perhaps you've been unlucky?

Comment: Because no one in spain (or france or italy, for example) would ever drink apple juice for lunch or dinner.

Comment: that's a german thing to drink apple juice I suppose

Comment: @Geeo In France it is possible to order AJ btw.

Comment: @nicael everywhere "it's possible" but in many restaurants it's highly unlikely they would have it

Comment: @Geeo It's uncommon to drink fruit juices or soft drinks with meals in France but most restaurants will stock them (for kids and *apéritif*). High end restaurants might eschew the soft drinks but not the fruit juice and apple is among the most common. So that's not the explanation.

Comment: Some juices (e.g. orange or cranberry) are the kinds of things you might keep on hand in a well stocked bar as mixes, which means you have them in stock to serve if someone wants them straight too. Apple juice is much less commonly used for this purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Spain apple juice is not as common as some other juices, but it is not the only one, in particular cranberry juice is also hard to find. Spain has always been a big producer of oranges, and the provinces of [Valencia](http://www.culturespain.com/2011/04/16/valencian-oranges/) and [Seville](http://www.southern-spain-travel.com/seville-orange.html) in the south of the country are particularly renowned for the fruit.

So it's no surprise that orange juice is common and popular.

You will find that most apple orchards tend to be in the north in provinces like [Asturias](http://www.spain.info/en_GB/reportajes/turismo_agroalimentario_artesanal_asturias.html), and most apples that are not produced for eating will be made into cider.

However there is one location that will I'm sure please you that you can almost always find apple juice in Spain: [McDonald's](http://www.mcdonalds.es/productos/bebidas-frias/tropicana-pure-premium-manzana).